# AngularJS, creating unique IDs on drag and drop event

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have two drag and drop lists. They are just supposed to transfer JSON objects from one list to another, not vice-versa. I achieved all that using Angular. 
However, when I want to drag from one list to another, I would like to generate an ID so that the transferred object is unique. Having a counter outside of my array doesn't seem to do the trick, because it first makes the transferred object's ID null, and then it starts counting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the existing code so that other can work on top of it..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore's `uniqueId` - just define a prefix and the full id will be autogenerated and will be unique: http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId

EDIT:
If you need just a number you can use it like this:

```
var id = +_.uniqueId();
```

Comment: I probably should have added that the 'unique' id should be just a number. All the new ids should just increment that value. For example: 1,2,3 etc :)

Comment: It's still the same with underscorejs. It just returns the same numbers as the counter.

Comment: Could you share your code via JSFiddle of something similar? I don't think I fully get what are you trying to achieve..